# Why can't I execute ffmpeg using shell_exec in a MAMP environment?

Tags: php, ffmpeg, mamp

I'm trying to run ffmpeg commands from php in my MAMP environment and it won't work. I've already added it to my path. I can run shell commands like whoami and ls -la with success but ffmpeg doesn't seem to work. I've also installed ffmpeg-php but it doesn't support the functions i need—Video > Image stack.

Example code:

```
<?php
    if (shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg")) 
        { echo "Success"; }
        else 
        { echo "No good"; }
?>
```

Comment: Does that command output anything? If not, I would think `shell_exec()` would return an empty string `""`, which would be treated as false and yield "No good" even if it ran.

Comment: if I run the above with -version I get output but if I run the following: <?php
 $output = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i file.mov -an -f image2 dir/file_%05d.png'");
 echo $output;
?> then shouldn't I see the result of the command? Here I am telling ffmpet to take a video and export all of the frames into a directory.

Comment: If I run the above in terminal, works fine.

Comment: Oh, so the files aren't being created? Is there a permissions issue on that directory?

Comment: I haven't setup any explicit permissions, should I?

Comment: Possibly. Try `777` on the directory. PHP may be running as a different user than you are directly in the shell.

Answer (score 2):

You should try to open the file /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/envvars and then comment the four lines of if and else. This will looks like this:

```
#if test "x$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH" != "x" ; then
#  DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
#else
#  DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib"
```

It works fine for me! In my case I also setted up all project permission like 777. If you need to do this you need execute the terminal command

```
chmod -R 777 projectDirectory
```

on file htdocs directory.
 I hope that you can enjoy it. Good Lucky!

Comment: Commenting out those lines in the envvars file worked for me too. Any idea why?

Comment: Still doesn't work for me. I'm about to smash my face in with a hammer!! MEH!

Comment: This is really boring Greg. Remembering that I found this solution for a already old version of MAMP (one year ano). If you find the solution let us know. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

1.Find the file /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/envvars_

2.Rename this file to /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/envvars

3.Comment all lines of this file.

4.Write this:

```
PATH="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.6.10/bin:usr/local/bin:$PATH"

export PATH
```

Notice: php5.6.10 - you have to write your current php version

Answer (score -1):

This link on stackexchange works https://superuser.com/questions/404344/ffmpeg-works-on-terminal-not-with-php-exec

Add '2>&1' to the end of your command like this

```
<?php 
    $info = shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i '.$inputMp3Path.' 2>&1');
    var_dump($info);
?>
```